# Flask-sqlalchemy, Good practices for creating a session?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to clarify, do I take advantage of flask-sqlalchemy when creating a session in this way?

```
from app import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Database():
   def __init__(self) -> None:
       with Session(db.engine) as session:
           self.session = session
```

Comment: If you are using Flask SQLAlchemy just use `db.session`.  Flask-SQLAlchemy manages the session lifecycle automatically, you just need to make sure you `add` and `commit`.

Comment: yes, but the second way is more convenient, among other things.